# Connecting azure database container from local machine?

Tags: azure, cassandra, azure-cloud-services, azure-container-service

I want to load data from local machine into Cassandra database running on azure cloud container services. I am new to Azure and I am pretty sure I need to enable something to make connection to azure cloud from outside network.

I created docker swarm cluster in Azure container services and deployed Cassandra docker container. I have a public IP to access the container and am trying to use public IP to connect to cassandra container, from my local machine, to load data. However, when I ran my java program which connects to Cassandra database, through host, I am getting error

```
DEBUG com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection - [Control connection] error on
```

I appreciate your time and help.
Thank you

Comment: Which container service do you use? AKS? ACI? Maybe you do not expose the port to the public IP. You can provide more info about your container.

Comment: acs, thank you for your interest. I was able to solve the issue. However, my understanding is still vague and I believe it's not very secure at the moment. I plan on going over it again

Comment: OK, if you have a great solution you can add the answer to share your achievement. Or need help please let me know.

Comment: thank you, I will do that. In my previous attempt I have tried multiple options to make it work and I don't know which approach actually worked for me. I will go over again and list all the steps probably by EOD. I'll also do more research from security stand point because I have exposed port and that is a red flag.